# How to escape special characters of a string with single backslashes

Tags: python, escaping

I'm trying to escape the characters `-]\^$*.` each with a single backslash `\`.

For example the string: `^stack.*/overflo\w$arr=1` will become:

```
\^stack\.\*/overflo\\w\$arr=1
```

What's the most efficient way to do that in Python?

`re.escape` double escapes which isn't what I want:

```
'\\^stack\\.\\*\\/overflow\\$arr\\=1'
```

I need this to escape for something else (nginx).

Comment: "`re.escape` double escapes which isn't what I want:" No, it doesn't; and yes, it is. The string shown here contains single backslashes, not double backslashes. They are **represented as** double backslashes for the same reason that there are single quotes surrounding it: because you are looking at a **representation of** the string as though it were Python source code. See [why do backslashes appear twice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24085680/).

Answer (score 162, accepted):

This is one way to do it (in Python 3.x):

```
escaped = a_string.translate(str.maketrans({"-":  r"\-",
                                          "]":  r"\]",
                                          "\\": r"\\",
                                          "^":  r"\^",
                                          "$":  r"\$",
                                          "*":  r"\*",
                                          ".":  r"\."}))
```

For reference, for escaping strings to use in regex:

```
import re
escaped = re.escape(a_string)
```

Comment: @hcwhsa `string.translate` as in `a_variable_called_string.translate`, rather than a function called translate in the module string.

Comment: Should mention, maketrans is in python 3, not python 2.x

Comment: `maketrans()` is still in Python 2. It's in the string module, not the str object: https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.maketrans

Comment: maketrans in python2 behaves very differently, requiring the input and output strings to be of the same length, and it doesn't accept dictionary inputs.  It's not so good for doing these kinds of translations.

Answer (score 26):

Just *assuming* this is for a regular expression, use [`re.escape`](http://docs.python.org/3.4/library/re.html#re.escape).

Comment: Note in lieu of dv: The author edited the question after this answer was posted to clarify that re.escape isn't what they're looking for.

Comment: @Air: I’ll look into exact incompatibilities at some point, but the author of the question was under the impression that it didn’t work because it double-escaped, but that was because they were using it in the REPL and that was the `repr()`. It doesn’t actually do that and does work in Nginx for the example given.

Answer (score 15):

We could use built-in function `repr()` or string interpolation `fr'{}'` escape all backwardslashs `\` in Python 3.7.*

`repr('my_string')` or `fr'{my_string}'`

Check the Link: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#repr

Comment: Doing `fr'{my_string}'` **will not change the string contents**. It is equivalent to `f'{my_string}'` (because the `r` only applies at the time the *string literal* is interpreted, and none of `{`, `m`, `y`, `_`, `s`, `t`, `r`, `i`, `n`, `g`, `}` require escaping), which is equivalent to `str(my_string)` (because that's what the f-string will end up doing), which is equivalent to `my_string` (because it was already a string). This doesn't solve the problem because it requires the *code that created `my_string` to have already solved the problem*.

Comment: As for `repr`, it will also surround the string in quotes, which may not be desired; and out of the characters described, it will **only** escape the backslash - did you **try it**? *This answer is completely wrong.*

Answer (score 13):

`re.escape` doesn't double escape. It just looks like it does if you run in the repl. The second layer of escaping is caused by outputting to the screen.

When using the repl, try using `print` to see what is really in the string.

```
$ python
>>> import re
>>> re.escape("\^stack\.\*/overflo\\w\$arr=1")
'\\\\\\^stack\\\\\\.\\\\\\*\\/overflo\\\\w\\\\\\$arr\\=1'
>>> print re.escape("\^stack\.\*/overflo\\w\$arr=1")
\\\^stack\\\.\\\*\/overflo\\w\\\$arr\=1
>>>
```

Answer (score 4):

Simply using `re.sub` might also work instead of `str.maketrans`. And this would also work in python 2.x

```
>>> print(re.sub(r'(\-|\]|\^|\$|\*|\.|\\)',lambda m:{'-':'\-',']':'\]','\\':'\\\\','^':'\^','$':'\$','*':'\*','.':'\.'}[m.group()],"^stack.*/overflo\w$arr=1"))
\^stack\.\*/overflo\\w\$arr=1
```

Answer (score -1):

Utilize the output of built-in `repr` to deal with `\r\n\t` and process the output of `re.escape` is what you want:

```
re.escape(repr(a)[1:-1]).replace('\\\\', '\\')
```