# Unable to make the xpath work with escapes

Tags: python, selenium

I am currently using an xpath to check if the id and placeholder match:

I have written this xpath, however I am having issues with escapes. I am not sure how to approach this

```
self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id="searchvalue" and @placeholder="Searched for: L1-Multi-level Combo   contains \'Corporate\General Counsel's Office (GCO)\'"]").click()
```

This is how my HTML code looks like:

```
<input type="text" name="searchvalue" id="searchvalue" placeholder="Searched for: L1-Multi-level Combo   contains 'Corporate\General Counsel's Office (GCO)\'" label="Search" title="Searched for: L1-Multi-level Combo   contains 'Corporate\General Counsel's Office (GCO)\'" class="uneditable-inputRight searchtext" onkeypress="if((event&amp;&amp;event.which==13)||(window.event&amp;&amp;window.event.keyCode==13)){quickSearchArcadia(gbappid, false, gbentity);}" onfocus="showSearchOptions()">
```

Comment: Try `'//input[@id="searchvalue" and @placeholder="Searched for: L1-Multi-level Combo   contains \'Corporate\General Counsel\'s Office (GCO)\'"]'`

Comment: whats the issue?

Comment: @Andersson, it does not work. I have added my HTML code screenshot

Comment: You'd better provide it as text, not as image

Comment: You could try storing that escaped string as a variable, and then just pass the variable, although I don't thing that's the "correct" solution.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to escape special characters of a string with single backslashes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18935754/how-to-escape-special-characters-of-a-string-with-single-backslashes)

Comment: @Andersson, sorry i added the text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually using `id` attribute should be enough to locate required element as it have to be unique value

```
self.driver.find_element_by_id("searchvalue")
```

but if you still want to use `placeholder` attribute also, try below expression:

```
self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@id="searchvalue" and @placeholder="Searched for: L1-Multi-level Combo   contains \'Corporate\\General Counsel\'s Office (GCO)\\\'"]')
```