# Is there a method in python string that will automatically escape characters for me in the output string

Tags: python, bash, sed, grep

I am currently running into a problem. I have a python script that takes a linux command , adds parameters to that command and then executes it. The command is a combination of `grep` and `sed`. Now the problem is in grep I do not need to escape the characters in my string as shown below. However when I do a sed and I need to use the same variable I need to make sure that the special variable characters are escaped first in the string. Like in the following example I have to rewrite the variable `oldpath` and `newpath` to `oldpath_sed` and `newpath_sed` . My question is if there is a way for me to reuse my current variables . Is there a python method that will escape special characters for me ?

```
oldpath = "/myfolder/subfolderA/"
newpath = "/myfolder/subfolderB/"

#Ill be using the following variables as a parameter to a linux sed commmand which requires me to escape characters  
oldpath_sed = "\/myfolder\/subfolderA\/"
newpath_sed = "\/myfolder\/subfolderB\/"

command = "grep -rl {0} {1} | sudo xargs sed -i 's/{2}/{3}/g'"
newcommand = command.format(oldString,folderName,oldString_sed,newString_sed)

ps = subprocess.Popen(newcommand,shell=True,stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
output = ps.communicate()[0]
```

Comment: If you use `sed` command as: `sed 's~{2}~{3}~g'` then you don't need to escape `/`

Comment: hmm let me try that

Comment: maybe take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18935754/how-to-escape-special-characters-of-a-string-with-single-backslashes