# Getting error while fetching value from file using Python and Django

Tags: python, xml, django

I need some help. I am trying to display the value in a tabular format but getting the following error using Django and Python. The error is given below.

> `raise SyntaxError("invalid predicate")`
>
> `SyntaxError: invalid predicate`

```
def search(request):
    per=[]
    if request.method == 'POST':
        rname=request.POST.get('rname')
        serch=request.POST.get('searchby')
        tree = ET.parse('roomlist.xml')
        root = tree.getroot()
        if serch==0:
           xyz = './/*[roomname='
           xyz = xyz + rname
           xyz= xyz + ']'
           result=root.findall(xyz)
           for x in result:
                  per.append({'roomname':x.find('roomname').text,'seat':x.find('noseats').text,'project':x.find('projectorscreen').text,'video':x.find('videoconf').text})
        return render(request,'booking/home.html',{'people': per})
```

My view part is given below.

> home.html:

```
{% if people %}
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>Room Name</th>
                <th>seats</th>
                <th>Projector screen</th>
                <th>Video Conference</th>
            </tr>
        {% for person in people %}
            <tr>
                <td>{{person.roomname}}</td>
                <td>{{person.seat}}</td>
                <td>{{person.project}}</td>
                <td>{{person.video}}</td>
            </tr>
        {% endfor %}
        </table>
    {% else %}
        <p>No Record in the database</p>
    {% endif %}
```

I need to fetch all value from the below `.xml` file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?><roomlist>
  <location name="Bangalore">
    <room id="1uy92j908u092">
      <roomname> Aquarius </roomname>
      <noseats> 10 </noseats>
      <projectorscreen>yes</projectorscreen>
      <videoconf>yes</videoconf>
    </room>
  </location>
<location name="Bhubaneswar"><room id="131198912460"><roomname>cottage</roomname><noseats>5</noseats><projectorscreen>Yes</projectorscreen><videoconf>Yes</videoconf></room></location><location name="puri"><room id="509955554930"><roomname>room1</roomname><noseats>10</noseats><projectorscreen>No</projectorscreen><videoconf>Yes</videoconf></room></location></roomlist>
```

Here I need to search all value from file and display. Please help me.

Comment: Please post full traceback.

Comment: Actually I am getting the error in this `result=root.findall(xyz)` line.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using `xml` module to parse xmls. Unfortunatelly `findall` of `xml` module only [supports subset of xpath](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#supported-xpath-syntax).

So my suggestion would be to use `lxml` instead:

```
from lxml import  etree as ET
```

and then:

```
if serch==0:
    xyz = './/room/roomname[text()="{}"]'.format(rname)
    result=root.xpath(xyz)
```

Comment: suppose I have `rname='cottage/'` then in this case how to escape the special string.

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18935754/how-to-escape-special-characters-of-a-string-with-single-backslashes) you can find some help on escaping characters.