# ' not being escaped in url and so param gets cut off

Tags: django, url-parameters

I have a url param that takes a name as a paramater, in this case:

```
Gino's%20East%20-%20Gold%20Coast
```

Notice how the spaces are being escaped, but the `'` is not. The escape for `'` is `%27`. This is breaking my django code. The `'` is acting as a string delimiter so

```
Gino's East - Gold Coast
```

becomes

```
Gino
```

and then I get a 404 because I have no venue named `Gino`. I am trying to solve the early delimit issue so when there is a `'` in a param it persists and also does not cut off the string.

How would one do this?

I thought the first answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18935754/how-to-escape-special-characters-of-a-string-with-single-backslashes) might be what I was looking for, but it wasn't.

Comment: It's not really clear how you are creating these URLs. Show some code. Although really you should not use strings like this as URLs anyway, you should use slugs - in this case "ginos-east-gold-coast".

Comment: interesting I will need to create a new type of entry in the database or at least deal with this for now. Thank you