# How do I match string using regex when there is small bracket in string?

Tags: python, regex

Suppose, I have two strings:

```
A = 'Ecology (miscellaneous)'
B = 'Ecology (miscellaneous)'
```

I want to find whether they match or not using regular expressions.`if (A == B)` works fine, but, I want to use regex.

```
re.match (A,B)
```

This does not work because of small brackets in the string. What is the best way to do it?. I am not used to with regular expressions; I am learning.

Comment: [This might be relevant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18935754/how-to-escape-special-characters-of-a-string-with-single-backslashes)

Comment: What *regex* did you try? also, this is **one** string, could you share more? Otherwise the *regex* might not match them all. For your case: `A = 'Ecology \(miscellaneous\)'`

Comment: try `re.escape(A)` to escape all special regex characters

Comment: Why do you want to use regular expressions?

Comment: I need to implement it with pandas `df.str.match()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use [`re.escape`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/re.html#re.escape) on the one string you want to treat as the pattern and just pass the other as is:

```
import re

A = 'Ecology (miscellaneous)'
B = 'Ecology (miscellaneous)'

print(bool(re.match(re.escape(A), B)))
```

> Output:
>
> ```
> True
> ```