# How do I write to a file with spaces and special characters in file name?

Tags: python, file, fwrite

I'm trying to write to a file called

```
data/STO: INVE-B-TIME_SERIES_DAILY_ADJUSTED-1.csv
```

using the following python code on windows

```py
overwrite = "w"  # or write new

f = open(OutputPath(copyNr), overwrite)
f.write(response.content.decode('utf-8'))
f.close()

print(f"Wrote to file: {OutputPath(copyNr)}")
```

The output in the console is correct, but the file written to results in only `data/STO` so the path seems to be clipped. I've tried to escape the characters using the method from this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18935765/4700818) but that gave me an invalid_argument exception for the following filename:

```
data/STO\\:\\ INVE-B-TIME_SERIES_DAILY_ADJUSTED-1.csv
```

I get the same error when I remove the space and it still seems to clip at `:`. How do I include such characters in a filename?

Comment: Windows does not allow colons in a filename.  You can't do it.

Comment: Oh, that explains it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. Colons are only allowed on the volumeseperator - anywhere else there are illegal.

Allowed:

```
d:/somedir/somefile.txt
```

Illegal:

```
./some:dir/somefile.txt
```

and as seperators you can either use `'\\'` or `'/'` - both should be understood.

This is not a python limitation  but a operating system limitation.

See f.e. [What characters are forbidden in Windows and Linux directory names?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1976007/what-characters-are-forbidden-in-windows-and-linux-directory-names)

Answer (score 0):

Windows API will not allow colon in filename, it is reserved for drive letter, use a different sign.